# What statistical test do I use?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, inference

| Feature | USA | Texas | California | India | Africa |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| No. of houses | 15000 | 2500 | 1900 | 1200 | 4000 |
| No. of schools | 11000 | 4500 | 1900 | 1000 | 1500 |
| No. of Churches | 6000 | 500 | 500 | 150 | 1200 |
| No. of Fast foods | 200000 | 91500 | 18000 | 1500 | 11000 |
| No. of Libraries | 5040 | 500 | 560 | 5000 | 8000 |
| No. of hospitals | 35000 | 1340 | 5093 | 1000 | 5400 |

I want to check if there is a statistically significant difference between the USA and all of Texas, California, India, and Africa for all the features in the table individually. If it matters, I also have counts of the total number of buildings in the USA, Texas, California, India, and Africa.

Comment: It is important for you to describe what these counts mean: how were they obtained?

Comment: @whuber These counts are the counts of different types of buildings in each country/state/continent. I also have the total count of all the buildings in each country/state/continent.

Comment: Are they *total* counts--that is, a complete census--or counts of *samples?*  Why do you view the counts of all buildings as relevant?  There's something mysterious about what you are trying to accomplish with this analysis and it would help to clear that up.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that a $\chi^2$ homogeneity test on the contingency table you show whould do what you are after. This assumes you regard each of the countries or states you list as random mechanisms generating schools, libraries, etc. in certain proportions and you want to test equality of those proportions.

Comment: The USA column likely is not independent of the state columns, so a direct application of a chi-squared test could be incorrect.  We really need to know what these counts actually represent.

Comment: @whuber, one could subtract the state columns an replace USA by "rest of USA", I guess.

Comment: That's a natural supposition.  But there's nothing in the question to indicate it's correct: we don't know that the state data are a subset of the USA data.  In fact, the "No. of Churches" line, if accurate, demonstrates this cannot possibly be the case: your proposal would result in a *negative* count for the US!

Comment: @whuber, right. My implicit assumption was that a sample was taken from the whole, then allocated to states & countries. Indeed some clarification from the OP is needed.

Comment: I am a bit lost. If I look for a chi 2 test of homogeneity https://www.displayr.com/what-is-the-chi-square-test-of-homogeneity/ this is used when there are $k$ categories, $n$ groups, and the $H_0$ hypothesis is that $p(k|group)$ is independent of the group. Here the "groups" could be USA, Texas, California, but what are the categories? I think you suggest that the categories are the types of building but this is not an exaustive list. So you would need to have an other column "none of the above". Does it make sense to make such a test without that column ?

Answer (score -1):

It seems you want to test whether 2 or more known values (e.g. 15000 vs 2500) are different, which makes little sense in terms of hypothesis testing.

See [this answer from quora](https://www.quora.com/Can-I-compare-just-two-values-to-see-if-they-are-statistically-significantly-different-from-one-another-or-do-I-need-to-have-a-sample-of-each-set-of-numbers-in-each-group-I-e-I-want-to-know-the-P-value-of-comparing-4-727-to-2-994) for further details.

Comment: You seem to assume this table describes an entire population.  Obviously it does not describe the entireties of the named countries and states, but perhaps it is focusing on some defined subpopulation.  The correctness of your answer therefore depends on missing information.  Let's hope the OP will supply some.